# Google Chrome console.log cached?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, tampermonkey

Sometimes when I'm using objects inside an userscript and using the TamperMonkey extension to run it, `chrome's console.log()` function is cached.
The code that effect it is this. The two `console.log(save);` always prints the same, although the will **never** be the same. However if I change `console.log(save[testID]['lastCheck']);` it will print differently.

```
function parseTestOverview(DOM)
{
    console.log(save);
    save[testID]['lastCheck'] = Date.now();
    var attempts = DOM.getElementsByClassName('answered');
    if(attempts.length == 0)
    {
        save[testID]['attempts'] = undefined;
        save[testID]['lastAttempt'] = undefined;
        save[testID]['lastAttempts'] = undefined;
        save[testID]['updated'] = false;
    }
    else if(save['lastAttempts'] || save['lastAttempts'] < attempts.length)
    {
        save[testID]['attempts'] = parseAttempts(attempts);
        var dateString = attempts[attempts.length - 1].innerText
            var dateTime = dateString.split(' ');
        var date = dateTime[0].split('-');
        var time = dateTime[1].split(':');
        save[testID]['lastAttempt'] = (new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], time[0], time[1])).getTime();
        save[testID]['lastAttempts'] = attempts.length;
        save[testID]['updated'] = false;
    }
    else
    {
        save[testID]['updated'] = true;
    }
    GM_setValue('save', save);
    console.log(save);
    return attempts;
}
```

This may not make any out of context so here is the whole script: http://pastebin.com/u1qqCrt2

This may not make any sense either, because it is a site-specific script.

I'm running 15.0.859.0 canary on Mac OS X 10.7.1

Comment: You say "TamperScript" but you're really running TamperMonkey, yes? (The former normally is just a helper for installing scripts on the latter.) ... ...  Please make a standalone demo of the problem that does not require a login!  (Nor, ideally, Danish language skills. ;) ) ... ... Finally, `GM_setValue()` cannot store an object so easily in FireFox.  It may be different in Chrome (I haven't tested yet) but that could be the problem.

Comment: Yup I mean "TamperMonkey" and GM_setValue with objects seems to work in it. About making a standalone demo, I don't want to use hours to recreate the website and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because webkit only shows the value of the object when it is expanded in the console, not when it is printed.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249333/640584