# console.log inconsistent with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I have reason to believe `console.log` and `JSON.stringify` can produce inconsistent views of the same object even if it was created in a straightforward manner (see notes).

**Situation**

In both Google Chrome developer tools and Firebug, I had an object `obj` which `console.log` printed out as `{ players: {0: ...}, ...}`, while `JSON.stringify` reported `{ players: {}, ...}`. `obj.players` was `{}` under both functions, so it seems that `console.log` is the culprit. Could it be asynchronous/non-deterministic in some way?

**Additional notes**

I'm afraid I won't be able to provide much more context, since the code is lengthy and for a client, but I can try if there is something that could help get to the bottom this. For the moment, I am forced to stay away from `console.log` for inspection.

It might be useful to know that the object is formed merely from an object literal by setting properties by hand, e.g., `obj.players = {}; obj.players[0] = ...`.

**Code**

A sample of what I mean can be observed at http://jsfiddle.net/9dcJP/.

Comment: Why not just `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` ?

Comment: Without providing the code, you could copy the JSON object and the two calls to a jsfiddle to show it reproduced in the simplest case.

Comment: Sorry, `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` was what I meant by using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should report with the keys enclosed by quotes, and `obj.players.0` is a syntax error. Do you perhaps have a specific testcase available?

Comment: Oops, meant `obj.players[0]`. I've put up a test case on jsfiddle now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does javascript object show different values in console in Chrome, Firefox, Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox)

Comment: `console.log` does have some asynch issues in Chrome if you pass it an object and then modify that object immediately.  You can work around it by reducing what you pass to `console.log` to a string first since strings are immutable, nothing gets changed before it's output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you just use `console.dir(obj)` instead? Or use `console.log(obj)` and then click on the output / expand it?

Also when I try the following code:

```
var obj = {};
obj.players = {};
obj.players[0] = {color: "green"};
obj.players[1] = {color: "blue"};
obj.world = "xyz";
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I always (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) get this as output:

```
{"players":{"0":{"color":"green"},"1":{"color":"blue"}},"world":"xyz"}
```

Furthermore it looks like your `players` object is actually an array. So you should better create it as such.

**Update:**
I just saw that you added a link to a JSFIDDLE demo, which empties the `players` object right after logging it. To my knowledge all web dev tools use some kind of asynchronous display, which results in an empty `players` object when using `console.log(obj)` or `console.dir(obj)`. Firebug thereby offers the best results by displaying the object correctly using `console.dir(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question - yes, console.log operations are [asynchronous](https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/) so can't be relied upon to print accurate values in the console - especially if you modify the printed object straight after the console.log call (like you are doing).

If you take away the line:

```
obj.players = {};
```

then both the differences between the plain console.log and the JSON.stringify dissappear.

Bearing in mind that there is a difference between logging a real object in a developer tools console (console.log(obj) and printing the stringified version of the object (console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))). So the representation of the object will still be different.