# Please explain why JSON.stringify output differs from toString output in this short example

Tags: javascript, json

This looks similar to [console.log inconsistent with JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733802/console-log-inconsistent-with-json-stringify), but: I'd like to know what exactly happens behind the screen, because I can't understand what exactly happens here, and why JSON.stringify() does not show the error text. Here's my code (saved in firstio.js)

```
var fs = require('fs')

try {
  var file = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error.toString());
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  process.exit()
}
console.log(file.toString().split("\n").length - 1)
```

when run as follows: `node firstio.js` the output is as follows:

```
TypeError: path must be a string
{}
```

If JSON.stringify is converting the error object where is the error text that toString() apparently *can* find?

When it is run as follows: `node firstio.js nonexistingfile` the output is:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'nonexistingfile'
{
  "errno": -2,
  "code": "ENOENT",
  "path": "nonexistingfile",
  "syscall": "open"
}
```

Comment: Because it's two entirely different functions?

Comment: stringify process enumarable properties. Maybe error does not have any.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify

Comment: Ok, while searching for a PHP-like var_dump() for Javascript, the top answers here on SO mentioned JSON.stringify(), but - as I found and wondered about - that does not work for the error variable.

Turns out that is the answer: the error variable is not an enumerable object. Thanks @Radek Pech. I'll mark your answer.
Which still leaves the question does JS have a var_dump() equivalent. No it does not, though console.dir() seems to come close.

Comment: Radek, if you create an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `JSON.stringify()` process objects based on their [enumarable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

But `window.Error` object does not have any enumerable properties thus `JSON.stringify(error)` returns only empty object.

You can write an error directly into console:

```
console.log(new Error('Something happened'));
```

Which will output `Error: Something happened`.

Or you can write your own method to stringify error; see [Is it not possible to stringify an Error using JSON.stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391212/is-it-not-possible-to-stringify-an-error-using-json-stringify)