# javascript array.sort not working with integers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with javascript array sorting and integers. I have these functions defined:

```
function sortA(a,b){ 
  return a - b;
}
function sortD(a,b){ 
  return b - a;
}
```

then in a jquery $.each, I put some content in the arrays:

```
$('.'+sort_column).each(function(index, value) {

    var current_num = $.trim($(this).text())

    current_num = parseInt(current_num, 10); //convert to integer for numeric sorting.

    valuesArr.push(current_num);  

    console.log(typeof index); //just checking...this shows number in the console
});

var sort_asc = valuesArr.sort(sortA);
var sort_desc = valuesArr.sort(sortD);
console.log(sort_asc);
console.log(sort_desc);
```

but in the console, I get the arrays in the same order.

```
//console
[1214500, 1214499, 1214497, 1214481, 1214432, 1214421, 1214419, 1214418, 1214369, 1214045, 1205691]
[1214500, 1214499, 1214497, 1214481, 1214432, 1214421, 1214419, 1214418, 1214369, 1214045, 1205691]
```

curiously, if I append a string to the end, the sorting works

```
console.log( valuesArr.sort(sortD)  + "asdf");
console.log( valuesArr.sort(sortA)  + "asdf");

//console
[1214500,1214499,1214497,1214481,1214432,1214421,1214419,1214418,1214369,1214045,1205691asdf] 
[1205691,1214045,1214369,1214418,1214419,1214421,1214432,1214481,1214497,1214499,1214500asdf]
```

I don't know why I even tried that, but there you go. This is the first time I've worked with this method, so I've likely missed something quite basic. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: there is a gotcha with the chrome console that it doesn't log an object's state at the time of logging, when you do `+ "asd"`, it logs a string, not an object, so it logs "correctly".

Comment: @Esailija: That's correct, but Chrome's `console.log` converts arrays into strings anyway.

Comment: @Esailija: Okay. I don't really understand the "doesn't log an object's state at the time of logging". Which state does it log? ^^ And by making new variables for the new arrays `var sort_asc = valuesArr.sort(sortA); var sort_desc = valuesArr.sort(sortD);` how can it even display those if the instant they're created they're populated with the sorted values? I also don't really understand why making the object into a string would give a more accurate picture. Sorry..that was a lot of questions..

Comment: @thomas it's not directly related to your problem, just the first thing that popped into my head, and chrome seems to have fixed it for arrays anyway. The real problem is that a new array is not created with `.sort` so you're sorting the same array all the time and only the last result will be thus visible to you. See Felix Kling's answer

Comment: @thomas: Esailija was referring to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox), which is important to know about, but does  not apply in your case.

Comment: this is still really interesting and good to know. thanks!

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear though on if this _isn't_ my problem, why appending a text string to the end seemed to solve the issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sorting the same array's instance, that's why the order is the same. Basically [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) changes the content of the array itself.

So both of them will be in desc order (that is the last sorting you're doing). If you want to keep the original instance intact, you should create new arrays:

```
var sort_asc = valuesArr.slice(0).sort(sortA);
var sort_desc = valuesArr.slice(0).sort(sortD);

console.log(valuesArr);
console.log(sort_asc);
console.log(sort_desc);
```

See also [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 2):

[`.sort()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array **in-place**. Both variables `sort_asc` and `sort_desc` reference the same array and therefore the output is the same.

Comment: Can you explain a little further why you use slice instead of just `var sort_asc = valuesArr; sort_desc = valuesArr;`? Thanks

Comment: @thomas: I think you refer to Zer0's answer ;) You cannot sort the same array in two different ways at the same time. `.slice` will create a copy of the array, which then is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply change your `sortA()` and `sortD()` like following:

```
function sortA(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a - b;
    });
}

function sortD(arr) {
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
       return b - a;
    });
}
```

And then use like following:

```
var myarr = [1214500, 1214499, 1214497, 1214481, 1214432, 1214421, 
             1214419, 1214418, 1214369, 1214045, 1205691];

sortA(myarr);

sortD(myArr);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/3RTkH/3/)**

Comment: What's the advantage? How does this related to the problem?

Comment: @FelixKling I think OP has problem of sorting array and above solution works well. If I misunderstand OP's point then please comment me

Comment: The OP was confused about the output of the sort operation, since he did not know that the arrays are sorted in-place. But the way he uses `.sort` is correct.