# JSZip and Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I am a newbie in programming. I am trying to use JSZip to zip some files from HTML5 filesystem, and I found the following difference between JSZip and other kinds of objects. Could anyone explain this to me?

```
<script src="jszip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function a(){
    var x=new JSZip();
    console.log(x) //Strange, it shows a JSZip object with folder abc
    b();

    function b(){
        x.folder("abc");
        console.log(x) //also shows a JSZip object with folder abc
    }
}
a();

function c(){
    var y=new Array();
    console.log(y) //shows []
    d();

    function d(){
        y[0]="abc";
        console.log(y); //shows ["abc"]
    }
}

c();
</script>
```

Comment: Using chrome? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox/8249333#8249333

Comment: yes! so you mean its the problem of Chrome...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682225/251311 + http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex K. commented, this is a [feature of the Webkit inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox/8249333#8249333).

If you change your `console.log` lines to `console.log(JSON.stringify(x));`, the object will be evaluated at that point, showing that the object contains the properties that you expect.