# unable to get value from json that exists

Tags: javascript, json

Am puzzled now, like really puzzled:

got this javascript object:

```
{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 28,
    h: 25,
    itemid: "5FE6E709096C4B57999AABC3575AF5D8",
    moveable: true,
    type: "4",
    fontface: "",
    text: "ef00704dd40e4768a1b15c14af9b6c4b.png",
    fontsize: 0,
    color: "",
    opacity: "",
    align: 0
}​
```

if I do console.log(theaboveobject);
it outputs fine.

however if I do console.log(object.w)  or console.log(object.h)  I get 0 as the response
2 nights in a row this has done my head in now, whats going on, what am i missing?

```
    console.log(artworkLine); // this outputs fine as above
    console.log(artworkLine.w);  // says 0
    console.log(artworkLine.h);  // says 0
```

Comment: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

Comment: Can you put it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: What if you use any js debugger and see the actual value in runtime?

Comment: I am, am using chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/psucz/   is more towards what I have but here it works, what is getting me is the first console.log outputs the whole object, but property values are 0 no matter what I do or how I do it

Comment: @davethecoder: the fiddle works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a guess but personally I've experienced the similar things several times.

It's caused by how the browsers resolve reference to an object in console. It's done in runtime in a moment of unfolding it by clicking on it. And it's likely that on that moment the object is already filled with desired data.

More details about that: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/

If you try js debugger (i.e. the one built in chrome developer tools) and put a break to the line with `console.log(object);` - you would see the actual object values.

The issue can be demonstrated very easily:

1. Open http://jsfiddle.net/8jzvd/
2. Open console
3. Press jsfiddle Run button
4. Wait until `unfold` label appears
5. Click on `Object` (assuming you use google chrome browser)
6. You see the object with `foo` property specified

Now repeat the same, but on step 4 unfold the object **before** `unfold` label appears. And you'll see that results from step 6 are different.

Comment: the problem is one a web page, i have used console just to debug the object, and also stepped through the object, hell inside console i can get the value, but if i do console.log withing the code i get 0

Comment: @davethecoder: have you tried js debugger? As I stated - it's possible to see in the `console.log()` not the "precise" values

Comment: wtf ???  how can code not have a value, but chrome can   okay shall investigate this further

Comment: @davethecoder: exactly. In debugger you always check the actual values, and with `console.log` you can see not entirely accurate data.

Comment: very interesting,  hmmmm never ever seen this behaviour before

Comment: got it,   okay so your spot on actually,   im doing a call to get my file details as json, this tells me what the default width and height is and updates the object, its then supposed to the make it moveable / resizable, however i have neglected to place the call inside my success, so my function that sets the object on stage is a few nano seconds behind because its async   damn damn damn  how did i miss that one :-)   okay cool lesson learned :-)

Comment: @davethecoder: oh right. Anyway - good luck with your code :-)