# Data is dissapearing eventhough it is there at the same time

Tags: reactjs

anybody know why the data exists in line 267 but not in 268? Any help is appreciated , thank you.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fZit.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4yxp.png)

[full function with useEffect watching props value to trigger the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meNsq.png)

```
function createData() {
    //loop through employees and create obj array
    const emptyArray = [];
    let counter = 0;
    if (props.employees) {
      const rowData = props.employees.map((item) => {
        console.log(item.tests_taken);
        let objectDetails = {
          firstName: item.first_name,
          lastName: item.last_name
        };

        console.log(item);
        console.log(item.tests_taken[0]);
        if (item.tests_taken[0]) {
          console.log(item.tests_taken[0]);
          item.tests_taken[0].forEach((test) => {
            console.log(test[Object.keys(test)[0]]);
            console.log('yo');
            objectDetails = {
              ...objectDetails,
              id: counter,
              cefrLevel: test[Object.keys(test)[0]].overallScore.level,
              cefrDescription:
                test[Object.keys(test)[0]].overallScore.description,
              overallScore: test[Object.keys(test)[0]].overallScore.score + '%',
              assessmentDate: test[Object.keys(test)[0]].date
            };
            counter += 1;
            emptyArray.push(objectDetails);
          });
          //console.log(emptyArray);
          return objectDetails;
        }
        props.setEmployees(null);
      });
      setUsersArray(emptyArray);
      console.log(usersArray);
      return rowData;
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    createData();
  }, [props.employees]);
```

Comment: Because in line 261 it doesn't exist either

Comment: why does it exist in 267 tho?

Comment: give complete code here with sample data, will surely help

Comment: It doesn't exist on line 267. It's just that when you console log an obj in the console like that, it is evaluated lazily. It only existed when you checked the content (later, I guess)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21352337/6567275

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects

Comment: so i posted another image with the full function, I am using useEffect and watching props employees to trigger the function when employees gets populated. Is this the issue point?

Comment: try puting the console.log(usersArray) in useEffect after the function

Comment: @c0dm1u it gives me [undefined]