# Why I use JSON.stringify in safari and chrome to stringify a json get different result?

Tags: javascript, json

I just simply to use `JSON.stringify({"a": "123"})` to `stringify` a `json`

In chrome, the `"` semicolon will not be escaped, it will echo

```
JSON.stringify({"a": "123"})
"{"a":"123"}"
```

But if I use the same code in safari, the `"` semicolon will be escaped, like this

```
JSON.stringify({"a": "123"})
"{\"a\":\"123\"}"
```

I want to know the reason about why the chrome and safari have the different result

Comment: That's just different representations in different consoles, they are the same string. Try `.length`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does javascript object show different values in console in Chrome, Firefox, Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox)

Answer (score 5):

It's not about `JSON.stringify`, it's about how the console displays value literals.

Safari chooses to make the entire line a valid literal. I.e. you could copy-paste the entire line into Javascript source code, and it'd be valid.

[image: Safari displays "foo\"bar"]

Chrome opts to just add decorative `""` marks *around* the line to signify that it's a string value, but displays only the string contents as-is, without making it into a valid literal.

[image: Chrome displays "foo"bar"]

The advantage of Safari's method is that you can copy-paste values as code, while Chrome's advantage is that you can read a string's contents without needing to mentally parse it according to string escaping rules.