# Move element in array from certain index into 0

Tags: javascript

I guess i do something stupid so forgive me, but both methods don't change anything .

I want to move element from certain index - **into index 0** .
I have an array with 2 elements .

first way

```
console.log(index); //1
console.log(localProductPhotos);
localProductPhotos.unshift(localProductPhotos.splice(index, 1)[0]);
console.log(localProductPhotos);
```

array will stay/print the same order

second way

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
    localProductPhotos.move(index,0); //index prints 1
```

both cases the array prints the same order.

**EDIT**:

This is the print:

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCWlB.png)

**EDIT**:
The above works on a simple array of strings, but my array is array of blob files as you can see in the photo.

```
    var localProductPhotos=[];
//...
  localProductPhotos.push(file);
```

Comment: Why are you using splice?

Comment: please add an example.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Both of these look fine.

Comment: sorry i have edited to show my log.

Comment: @ninesalt this is the examples i see online, is it not good ?

Comment: That is just how the logging works. You log the same array with references to objects, so once you expand them you see their current state which is the swapped array. Try logging with `console.log(JSON.stringify(localProductPhotos));` in both cases and you will see your code works fine.

Comment: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440) and [Why does javascript object show different values in console in Chrome, Firefox, Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136)

Comment: thanks sorry i didn't get it. file number 3 did not change position inside the array. can you explain more ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thanks i tried but this way it prints empty - [{},{}]

Comment: @adiga it prints [{},{}]  with stringify

Comment: The important thing is that your code works. The problem is how the logging works (*the `JSON.stringify` cannot handle `File` objects*).
Try `console.log(localProductPhotos[0].name, localProductPhotos[1].name)`

Answer (score -2):

Based on your example/log, I can surmise that you want to move the element in your `index` to the first one. So you can just do this:

```
localProductPhotos.unshift(localProductPhotos[index]);
```