# Cannot access Javascript object key-value shown in console.log

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently implementing a modified version of [this](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4339083) D3 collapsible tree. When I am creating the links, there are two key-value pairs (`x0` and `y0`) that appear when I console log a certain object, but that are undefined when logged individually. They also are not listed in the object's keys when using the `Object.keys()` method. See below:

[image]

How do I access the missing values?

Comment: Are they dynamically added later? The console is lazy loading so it is not a snapshot that that moment in time. `console.log(JSON.stringify(d.source))`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. These console logs are on consecutive lines of synchronous code, so I don't think the object could have been modified in the interim.

`console.log(JSON.stringify(d.source))` does not work. I receive `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Comment: can you try log `d.source` in the end again?

Comment: and please explain why you need access to these properties.

Comment: @223seneca [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox) you don't need async code to trigger this behaviour: `obj = {a: 1}; console.log(obj); obj.a = 2;` will do it. You print `obj` but it's not a snapshot of what `obj` was at the time of printing it - it's printed as a "live object" (or the reference evaluated later). So, when you expand this, you'll see `a: 2` even though it was `a: 1` at the time of printing.

Comment: When I log `d.source` afterwards, the missing keys appear again. I need these properties in order to make the line transitions render properly.

Comment: and `Object.keys()` only returns enumerable property names (although it seems not the case)

Comment: These are enumerable property names, are they not?

Comment: They are enumerable but if you *don't* see them from `Object.keys` yet you see them when the object is printed, it suggest the issue is what @epascarello mentioned - the properties are added later. `Object.keys` *would* give you an accurate snapshot of the keys present at that point in time, printing the object doesn't.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I have no idea where these could be added later, though. It may be some nuance of D3.

Comment: `var a = {}; console.log(a); a.foo = '1';` inspect the object in the console.

Comment: Yes, I can replicate the behavior you're describing.