# Array different length in console.log at Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filereader, shapefile

Hellloo, it my first time find this in js
i am trying to put every data that is in the file into an array. And when I checked, there was an oddity, namely the odd array length.

this my code

```
export function convertGISToGeojson(file) {
  if (file) {
    let geojson = [];

    var promise = new Promise(getBuffer(file));

    promise
      .then(function (data) {
        geojson = data;
        console.log(geojson);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      });

    return geojson;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function getBuffer(fileData) {
  return function (resolve) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var shapefile = require("shapefile");
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    reader.onload = function () {
      let geojson = [];
      let result = reader.result;

      shapefile
        .open(result)
        .then((source) =>
          source.read().then(function log(result) {
            if (result.done) return;
            geojson.push(result.value);
            return source.read().then(log);
          })
        )
        .catch((error) => console.error(error.stack));

      resolve(geojson);
    };
  };
}
```

when i try to `console.log(data)` that variable, the result like this
[image: console my variable]
But, when i try to `console.log(data[0])`, the result is undefined

whats wrong with my code?

Comment: in which line you execute console.log(data) and in which line you execute console.log(data[0])

Comment: @Elias inside promise.then(........)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does javascript object show different values in console in Chrome, Firefox, Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox)

Comment: @Reyno it doesn't...

Comment: try console.log(data[0].value)

Comment: You already have an issue with your `convertGISToGeojson` function. You are returning before the promises resolves. `geojson` is possible empty at the point.

Comment: @Terry i was trying to use async, await, and promises resolves... but data that i get is like the image that i post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `convertGISToGeojson` and `getBuffer` functions doesn't do what you would expect, you're returning an empty array or null, you don't wait for the promise to resolve or resolve too early, use `async/await`. I wrapped both functions in the demo below:

```js
function convertGISToGeojson(fileArrayBuffer) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    //var shapefile = require("shapefile"); // uncomment this
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob([fileArrayBuffer], {
      type: "application/octet-stream"
    }))
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
      let result = reader.result;
      shapefile
        .open(result)
        .then((source) =>
          source.read().then(function log(result) {
            return source.read().then(i => resolve(i.value));
          })
        )
        .catch((error) => reject(error.stack));
    };
    reader.onerror = (event) => reject(reader.error);

  })

}


(async() => {

  let file = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/mbostock/shapefile/master/test/points.shp';
  let fileBuffer = await fetch(file).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

  convertGISToGeojson(fileBuffer)
    .then(info => console.log('info', info))
    .catch(err => console.log('err', err))

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/shapefile@0.6.6/dist/shapefile.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i check the return, it comes like this
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "pending"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

Comment: @Zenryo i have updated my answer with a working minimal example

Comment: thanks for the answer, it made me delve deeper into async/await

Answer (score -1):

Try `console.log(data[0])`  inside

```
promise
  .then(function (data) {
    geojson = data;
    console.log(data[0])
    console.log(geojson);
  })
```