# Vue reactive object has not-null value, but outputting value returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I've never seen anything like this before.  I have an object called `action` containing 3 properties (`actionType`, `faxNumber` and `guid`).

I do `console.log('action=', action, 'guid=', action.guid)` and get:

```
action = AutomationActionFax {__ob__: Observer}
   actionType: "fax",
   faxNumber: null,
   guid: "JHANQK1MQ",

guid = null <-- WTF???
```

How is is possible to see the property `guid` on the `action` set to `JHANQK1MQ`, then ask for `action.guid` in the same statement and have it return `null`?

Comment: can you attach the code block where you ve added the console statement?

Comment: Please keep in mind the objects might have the latest state in console. Try to output it using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Anatoly do you mean the objects might NOT have the latest state in the console?  If I `JSON.stringify` the `action`, indeed it outputs `guid = null`.  How on Earth is this even possible? How can the output of stringify NOT match the object being stringified?

Comment: Interesting, I think this answer explains the why.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249333/1598935

Comment: Exactly what I meant